# I am creating an e-commerce application using flutter and I want to save the data for the unregistered user locally. Is there any way to do that?

Tags: flutter, dart, e-commerce

Actually I wanted to save the cart items of the unregistered users locally not in the database so that the user who have not registered into the system can also add the products into their respective carts. Is there any way to do say that?

Comment: you can use [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared_preferences: ^2.0.6.

Setting data-

```
SaveUserDetais(String name) async {
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 await prefs.setString('name_of_user',name);
}
```

Getting Data-

```
Future<String> getUserDetails() async{
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance;
 return prefs.getString('name_of_user') ;
}
```

Suppose you user model is **UserInfo** then you can store data in following say

```
SaveUserDetails(UserInfo data) async {
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 await prefs.setString('user_info',json.encode(data));
}
```

And you can fetch data in same way as I described in getUserDetails method. You just have to change return type-

```
Future<UserInfo> getUserDetails() async{
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance;
 var data =prefs.getString('name_of_user') ;                               
 return UserInfo.frimJson(json.decode(data)) ;
}
```

Comment: But I want to store a model of cartitem not only a string. How can I do so?

Comment: Actually i wanted to store all the items that an unregistered user adds to his/her cart. For that i need to store the model of the cart item in a list. Is there any possible to do that using shared preference?

Comment: Please share your model code and the code where you want to perform

Comment: `class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  int quantity;
  final int price;
  final String image;
  final int stock;
  final double amount;
  final String unit;

  CartItem(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.quantity,
      required this.price,
      required this.image,
      required this.stock,
      required this.amount,
      required this.unit});`

This is the model. Now I want to save the model for an unregistered user whenever he wants to add any item in the cart.